# Rails get type of all objects in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I feel like this is a pretty basic question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Say I have an array of various things

```
things = [
  false,
  #<Product:0x007fc58a2d9ef0>,
  12,
  "some text"
]
```

Is there a way I can print out the type of each of those? Something like:

```
things.each do |thing|
  = thing.type
```

As opposed to having to specifically check if each one is something with `thing.is_a? String`

Comment: Do you mean the object's class? `= thing.class`

Comment: Are you attempting to find out if all of them is a given object?

Comment: `= thing.class` is very close, however ultimately what I'd like is for `#<Product:0x007fc58a2d9ef0` to be more generic than `Product`. Something like `Object` or `Model`

Comment: I was trying to use `.class.base_class` however that fails when the `thing` is a `boolean`. I can write an if/else to check for that but wondered if there was a better way

Comment: @JustinWood - yes. Basically I want to look though the array, and then if I find an object, check that object to see if it has a specific attribute.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to rearchitect so that you know where your objects are? How is this array being created?

Comment: @MarkThomas - The actual issue is quite a bit more complicated, and while I agree with you, it's not possible at the moment. I'm just trying to put a stopgap in place.

Comment: You may want to look into the [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, perhaps you want something like this:

```
things.select{|t| t.respond_to?(:base_class)}.each do |obj|
  #check obj.attr
end
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I've been looking for. Per the documentation, I tried it with `thing.respond_to("name")` and it returned true for the only object that had that attribute and false for booleans, strings, and objects with out that attribute; which was ultimately what I was looking for. Thank you for bring this to my attention!